# SQLite Recursive Intersection

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have sql query that takes in a Key  and it outputs a set of records {S}.

How do I create an SQLite Recursive Query that takes in a group of N keys  returns the intersection of all the sets { {S1}, {S2}, {S3} }

Without having to generate a copy/pasted SQL statement.

I'll give a simple example. So this is the obvious answer to intersect.

```
SELECT record from RecordSet where key = 'KEY1'
INTERSECT
SELECT record from RecordSet where key = 'KEY2'
```

What I don't want to have to do is copy and paste like so:

```
SELECT record from RecordSet where key = 'KEY1'
INTERSECT
SELECT record from RecordSet where key = 'KEY2'
INTERSECT
SELECT record from RecordSet where key = 'KEYN'
```

But rather use the recursive query functionality seen here:
WITH RECURSIVE [Example Here Under Recurisve Query Example](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html)

Where I can pass all the keys

```
SELECT key from KEYS where key in (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, ..., KEYN)
To this recursive query.
```

Comment: It's best if you post your current query. But it sounds like `where Key in (k1, k2, k3)` might be what you're after.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  An example of your data and desired output would help.  It may be that you need an aggregate function that counts all of the records (or a unique key thereof) and returns only those where the count is equal to N.

Comment: This depends on how the query actually uses the key (it's obviously not `key = 'KEY1'`).

Answer (score 1):

Try a query like this:

```
WITH abc AS(
  SELECT Kej, val,
         (SELECT count(DISTINCT kej) FROM mytable b WHERE b.kej < a.kej) As cnt
  FROM mytable a
),
bcd AS (
   SELECT * FROM abc WHERE cnt = (SELECT max(cnt) FROM abc)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT a.* FROM abc a
   JOIN bcd b ON a.cnt = b.cnt - 1 
              AND a.val = b.val
)
SELECT val FROM bcd
WHERE cnt = 0
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f5b54/1)
The above query works on the assumption that there is only one column checked for intersection.
If your table has N colums (val1, val2, ... valN), then the join must contain all these columns:

```
   JOIN bcd b ON a.cnt = b.cnt - 1 
              AND a.val1 = b.val1
              AND a.val2 = b.val2
              .....
              AND a.valN = b.valN
```